# What user am I currently logged in as?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian

I am using debian. Is there a command that will show me what user I am currently logged in as?

I want to use this command in a rails application that I'm building for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `whoami` command.

Answer (score 1):

"whoami" is the command for this

Answer (score 1):

In ruby/rails you can use

```
require 'etc'
Etc.getlogin
```

which returns the username of the current user (works on any platform!)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $USER

```
echo "The user is $USER"
```